# Bootstrap3 Resize map height for phone

Tags: leaflet, html, bootstrap-framework

I have a leaflet map in a bootstrap 3 html application. I have content both above and below the the map which has a height of 600px. When I access the application from a phone, the width of the map adjusts to the the width of the screen. However, the height of the map does not update and you end up with a seemingly endless map sandwiched between two chunks of content. The user must then endure endless scrolling. You can see what i mean here: http://punkmap.com/examples/fauxnmap/index.html

Anyone know what's the best way to handle this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  You may have noticed me remove your signature from your Question.  This is as per the help instructions and because every Question, Answer and Comment you post is already signed with your [**user card**](http://gis.stackexchange.com/users/27641/user3362424).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a [media query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile) to detect when the user is on a phone. Then use CSS to adjust the size of the map div accordingly. eg for an iPhone:

```
<style type="text/css">
  #map {height: 600px;}
  @media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px)  and (max-device-width : 568px){
    #map {height: 250px;}
  }
</style>
```

Demo [here](http://stephenlead.com/maps/mediaquery.html) - when I view this on my phone the map is reduced in size.

Comment: This is not what I need. I don’t want content to disappear, I just want the map (currently height: 600px) to have a smaller height when accessed by a phone. 

I know this is a CSS issue but I assume that that other GISers have come across this issue before and solved it and that future GISers will be glad to find this post if a solution is found and documented.

Comment: Got it - sorry. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Totally awesome! Thanks! This is exactly what I need. Happy mobile GISing folks?